# chatbot programming using CGI

Tags: xml, perl, textarea, cgi

I am programming a chatbot using CGI, i have an xml file with the patterns and  possible answers, i parse it and store the pattern with its answers in a hash.
i made an interface using HTML, i get the string introduced in an input textfield, and i check if it contains one of the patterns i have in my hash,  if yes it prints one of the possibles answers in a textarea(html) what it does not do, i don't know why .

what i want to have is something like this: http://nlp-addiction.com/chatbot/eliza/

here is a part of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<aiml version="1.0"> 
<category> 
      <pattern>SARA</pattern>
      <template> 
        <random> 
          <li>¿Si?</li>
          <li>Dime.</li>
          <li>¿Qué deseas?</li>
        </random>
      </template>
    </category>
    <category>
    <pattern>ACTOR</pattern>
      <template> 
        <random> 
          <li>Mi actor favorito es Arnold Schwarzenegger en "Terminator".</li>
          <li>Mi actor favorito es Rutger Hauer en "Blade Runner".</li>
          <li>Mi actor favorito es Robin Williams en "El Hombre Bicentenario".</li>
          <li>Mi actor favorito es Peter Weller en "Robocop".</li>
          <li>Mi actor favorito es Jude Law en "AI".</li>
        </random>
      </template>
    </category>
    <category>
    <pattern>ACTRIZ</pattern>
      <template> 
        <random> 
          <li>Mi actriz favorita es Daryl Hannah en "Blade Runner".</li>
          <li>Mi actriz favorita es Kristanna Loken en "Terminator 3".</li>
          <li>Mi actriz favorita es Persis Khambatta en "Star Trek".</li>
        </random>
      </template>
    </category>
    <category>
    <pattern>ADAM</pattern>
      <template> 
        <random> 
          <li>Adam es mi programador. En este momento está muy ocupado.</li>
          <li>Adam es mi botmaster. Le daré saludos de tu parte.</li>
        </random>
      </template>
    </category>
    <category>
    <pattern>ADIOS</pattern>
    <template> 
      <random>
        <li>Hasta luego.</li>
        <li>Espero haber sido de ayuda.</li>
        <li>Espero verte de nuevo.</li>
      </random>
    </template>
  </category>
  <category> 
      <pattern>AFICIONES</pattern>
      <template> 
        <random> 
          <li>Me gusta ayudar a la gente.</li>
          <li>Me gusta conversar con la gente en Internet.</li>
          <li>Me encanta visitar zonas turísticas en <bot name="ciudad"/>.</li>
        </random>
      </template>
    </category>
<category> 
  <pattern>AHORA</pattern>
  <template> 
    <random> 
      <li>En este momento estoy hablando contigo.</li>
      <li>Ahora estoy hablando contigo.</li>
    </random>
  </template>
</category>
</aiml>
```

and here is my program:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use CGI;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
use utf8;

print "Content-Type:text/html\n\n";

binmode(STDOUT,":utf8");
binmode(STDIN,":utf8");

my $query = new CGI;


my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xmlfile = $parser->parse_file('sara.xml'); 

my %words;

my @answers;

$xmlfile = $xmlfile->getDocumentElement(); 



my @kids  = $xmlfile->findnodes('//category');  

foreach  my $child (@kids) {

    my $pattern = $child->findvalue('pattern'); 
    @answers = $child->findnodes('template/random/li'); 

    for my $answer(@answers){

        push @{$words{$pattern}}, $answer->textContent; 
    }

} 

my $input;
my $reply;

if($query->param('input1')) {
    $input = ($query->param('input1') || "");
    }

while($query->param('input')) {

    foreach my $pattern(keys %words){
        if(index(uc $input, $pattern) != -1){

            @answers = @{words{$pattern}};
            my $n = int rand($#answers + 1);

            $reply = $answers[$n];
            last;   
        }   
    }


}

print  <<PAGE;
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Chat with Sara</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    input[type=text]{
        height:30px;

    }

    input[type=submit]{
        height:30px;
        width:65px; 
    }
    </style>
    <h1>Chat With Sara</h1>
    <form name="e_form" action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/chatbot.cgi" method="post">
    <textarea name="e_diaplay" cols="58" rows="20">$reply</textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name=\"input1\" size="50">
    <input type="submit" name="chat" value="Chat">
</head>
</html>
PAGE
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this ?

Any help ?

Comment: the variable $reply is not displayed in the textarea i don't know why.

Comment: i said what is the problem above !!!!!!

Comment: I don't understand why this question was voted down !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have a typo in the while, you are using input instead of input1

```
while($query->param('input')) {
```

You could add something to $reply to see it is displayed at all:

You should use foreach instead of while and you could use grep:

```
my $from_sara;
foreach my $input ($query->param('input1')){
  foreach my $pattern (grep {/^\s*$input\s*$/is} keys %words){
     @answers = @{$words{$pattern}};
     $from_sara = $answers[int rand($#answers + 1)];
     last;
  }
  last if $from_sara;
}
my $reply = "Answer from Sara:\n$from_sara\n";
```

Comment: this is what it displays: 
Answer from Sara:ARRAY(0xc9b570)

Comment: missing $ in  @{$words{$pattern}};